# Programmatically set the Don't Move or Size with Cells property for a Chart

Tags: excel, charts, vba

Using Excel 2007 VBA. I have a single Chart on a sheet that overlaps its source data. When cleaning up I hide the data rows, but the Chart is shrinking in height.

I know I can set the "Don't move or size with cells" to True, but I don't know how to do this programmatically from VBA. I tried just recording a macro, but it didn't show up.

Comment: Check out [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f3a7ff6-a196-41f2-a043-8cc2bebc9040/programmatically-change-positioning-move-and-size-with-cells-in-excel?forum=vsto) for how to handle this situation in Visual Studio Tools for Office and [this blog post](http://powerofexcel.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/excel-shapes-placement-property-set-by-vba/).  I think there's a `.Placement` property you can use, but I don't have the time to confirm and write an answer at the moment.

Comment: @thunderblaster, actually, I had seen the MSDN page before writing the question. The problem was that only `Shape`s have the `Placement` property, and my object is a `Chart`. I did some more searching (shifting the focus from "Move and size with cells" to how to get the `Shape` object associated with a `Chart`), and I found [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696493/access-a-charts-shape-id-excel-vba). Essentially, `myChart.Parent.Placement` has seemed to work initially. So I think I've got my answer.

Comment: Excellent.  If it's working for you, you should add it as an answer and accept it.  That may help others with the same problem.

Comment: Good idea. I'll add the answer after I do a little more testing to ensure things are working properly. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could have been a little more specific in my question by indicating that I had access to a `ChartObject` object in VBA. Therefore, when I came across various examples on the internet using `Shape.Placement = vbFreeFloating`, I wasn't sure how to use it on a `ChartObject`. As I mentioned in a comment above, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696493/access-a-charts-shape-id-excel-vba) mentions that you can access the `Shape` associated with a `ChartObject` by the using `ChartObject.Parent` property. Then it's simply a matter of doing `ChartObject.Parent.Placement = vbFreeFloating`. This appears to have solved my problem. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: for those stuck, in excel 2010 at least the constant is called `xlFreeFloating`